# Python code replace column value with space which is seperated by pipe delimiter in text file and after replacing the file has to be saved

Tags: python

In a text file I have data like this:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|su123|g

a|b|c|d|e|f|g|ma123|g
```

I want to develop a code in Python that goes to the column which is having alphanumeric data, replaces the value with a space and saves the changes in text file.

Comment: Please add the code you have developed so far so we can help you out.

Comment: import re
import os
for file in os.listdir("D:/EMHI"):
    if file.endswith(".tab"):
        print(file)
    
with open("D:" + "\\" + "EMHI" + "\\" + file, 'r') as file :
    data = file.read()

data = re.sub('([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*',' ', data)

with open("D:" + "\\" + "EMHI" + "\\" + "pyout.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)

Comment: i've added the code in that i specifically want to delete particular column.Like in my code i've 7th column,which means if 7th column is having alphanumeric data replace with space

Answer (score 1):

This is code to replace alphanumeric to space for only 8th column(index number: 7).

```
import re
import csv

result = []
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file :
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        data = row
        data[7] = re.sub('([0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9])[a-z0-9]*',' ', data[7])
        result.append(data)

with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Comment: See the 8th column which is having alphanumeric data (su123).That value should be replaced with space.otherwise dont replace

Comment: The entire column value should be replaced with space .last but one column is having data su123 which is alphanumeric in that place space should come.

Comment: import re
import os
for file in os.listdir("D:/EMHI"):
    if file.endswith(".tab"):
        print(file)
    
with open("D:" + "\\" + "EMHI" + "\\" + file, 'r') as file :
    data = file.read()

data = re.sub('([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*',' ', data)

with open("D:" + "\\" + "EMHI" + "\\" + "pyout.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)

Comment: i've added the code in that i specifically want to delete particular column.Like in my code i've 7th column,which means if 7th column is having alphanumeric data replace with space

Comment: Did you try my code? it works for replacing alphanumeric data to space

Comment: Dear Wonjin your code is working fine, many thanks for that. But i want seventh column to be replaced which is alphanumeric.I dont want other columns to be replaced with space  even if their data type is alphanumeric.please reply me soon.

Comment: Okay, I edited my code. First read file with delimiters, and replace only 7th column from alphanumeric to space.